# Separating two Images of Stereo Camera with opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera

I'm using opencv with my stereo camera(LI-USB30-V024 STEREO).
I want to print the two images of my stereo camera in two windows.
So first I printed the images in window like this.

```
void main(){

    IplImage* frame1;

    IplImage* frame2;
    CvCapture* cam1;
    CvCapture* cam2;
    cam1 = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    cam2 = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

    cvNamedWindow("sample1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("sample2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1){
        cvGrabFrame(cam1);
        frame1 = cvRetrieveFrame(cam1);

        cvGrabFrame(cam2);
        frame2 = cvRetrieveFrame(cam2);

        if (!frame1)
            break;
        cvShowImage("sample1", frame1);
        cvShowImage("sample2", frame2);

        if (cvWaitKey(10) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&cam1);
    cvReleaseCapture(&cam2);
    cvDestroyWindow("sample1");
    cvDestroyWindow("sample2");
}
```

But my problem is that the 2 images of camera printed together in one window.
How can I separate each of this 2 images?

Answer (score 1):

[User Interface](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) ,
Especially `imShow()` and `namedWindow()`.

In case you are on an Android device as the tag indicates the answer is: No you cant without a huge affort.